# Maven build Compilation error: cannot find symbol

Tags: maven

When I try to build this with maven I am getting compilation error which says that it can not find a symbol. It is build on Java 11.

```
 Error:  COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
Error:  /home/main/java/com/asdf/sdfl/sdfs/sdfsdft.java:[21,16] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class IOUtils
  location: package sun.misc
```

No matter how many times I build the project, i get the same error.
I am thinking that it may be because the package sun.misc is private package.
Is there anything I can add to pom.xml to fix this issue?

Here is my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <prerequisites>
    <maven>3.0.0</maven>
  </prerequisites>

  <groupId>com.carpics2p0.vendorportal</groupId>
  <artifactId>carpics2p0-vendorportal</artifactId>
  <version>0.1.0</version>
  <name>CarPics_2_0 Vendor Portal Application</name>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <dropwizard.version>1.0.6</dropwizard.version>
    <sonar.organization>carmedia2p0dotcom</sonar.organization>
    <sonar.host.url>https://sonarcloud.io</sonar.host.url>
  </properties>

  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>sonatype-nexus-snapshots</id>
      <name>Sonatype Nexus Snapshots</name>
      <url>http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
      <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-dynamodb</artifactId>
      <version>1.11.68</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
      <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-s3</artifactId>
      <version>1.11.66</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
      <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
      <version>19.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.dropwizard</groupId>
      <artifactId>dropwizard-core</artifactId>
      <version>${dropwizard.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.dropwizard</groupId>
      <artifactId>dropwizard-auth</artifactId>
      <version>${dropwizard.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.dropwizard</groupId>
      <artifactId>dropwizard-assets</artifactId>
      <version>${dropwizard.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.dropwizard</groupId>
      <artifactId>dropwizard-spdy</artifactId>
      <version>0.9.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.dropwizard</groupId>
      <artifactId>dropwizard-hibernate</artifactId>
      <version>${dropwizard.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.dropwizard</groupId>
      <artifactId>dropwizard-migrations</artifactId>
      <version>${dropwizard.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.dropwizard</groupId>
      <artifactId>dropwizard-client</artifactId>
      <version>${dropwizard.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.googlecode.soundlibs</groupId>
      <artifactId>mp3spi</artifactId>
      <version>1.9.5-1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.dropwizard</groupId>
      <artifactId>dropwizard-views-freemarker</artifactId>
      <version>${dropwizard.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.dropwizard</groupId>
      <artifactId>dropwizard-views-mustache</artifactId>
      <version>${dropwizard.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.dropwizard</groupId>
      <artifactId>dropwizard-testing</artifactId>
      <version>${dropwizard.version}</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpmime -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
      <artifactId>httpmime</artifactId>
      <version>4.5.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-httpclient/commons-httpclient -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-httpclient</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-httpclient</artifactId>
      <version>3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-io/commons-io -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
      <version>2.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>mysql</groupId>
      <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
      <version>6.0.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.thoughtworks.xstream</groupId>
      <artifactId>xstream</artifactId>
      <version>1.4.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.easymock</groupId>
      <artifactId>easymock</artifactId>
      <version>3.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.12</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-core -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
      <version>2.8.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-core -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
      <version>2.8.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-core -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
      <version>2.8.7</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
 
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <configuration>
              <source>1.8</source>
              <target>1.8</target>
          </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.1</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>attach-sources</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>jar</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
        <configuration>
          <archive>
            <manifest>
              <addDefaultImplementationEntries>true</addDefaultImplementationEntries>
            </manifest>
          </archive>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
        <configuration>
          <createDependencyReducedPom>true</createDependencyReducedPom>
          <filters>
            <filter>
              <artifact>*:*</artifact>
              <excludes>
                <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
              </excludes>
            </filter>
          </filters>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>shade</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <transformers>
                <transformer
                  implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ServicesResourceTransformer"/>
                <transformer
                  implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                  <mainClass>com.carpics2p0.vendorportal.VendorPortalApplication</mainClass>
                </transformer>
              </transformers>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <!-- You'll probably want to remove this for your project. I'm just using it here
             so that dropwizard-example doesn't get deployed as a library. -->
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.7</version>
        <configuration>
          <skip>true</skip>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Switch to Java 8 if you just need this to build now. The long term solution is to get proper replacements for all `sun.*` classes

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you imported `sun.misc.IOUtils` instead of `org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils` (from the commons-io library).